# IntelliJ cannot find packages imported

Tags: jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea

I checked out project from subversion.

It contains many folders and most of them have: Branch, Tag, trunk.

Part of the structure of my project:

```
myApp1 (module)
|__ .idea
|__ myApp1
    |__ DB
    |__ Accounting
    |__ Scheduler
        |__ branches
        |__ tag
        |__ trunk
            |__ DB Scripts
            |__ JavaSource
                |__ com
                |__ Components
                |__ Connection.java
            |__ WebContent
                |__ HTML
                |__ JSP
                |__ Javascript
                |__ web
                |__ pki
                    |__ index.jsp
                |__ WEB-INF
                    |__ applicationContext.xml
                    |__ faces-config.xml
                    |__ web.xml
```

And other folders: DB, Accounting also have similar structure as Scheduler does.

When I open this project in IntelliJ, in some .jsp pages it complains about not being able to find packages imported, i.e.:

`index.jsp` contents:

```
   <%@page import="com.security.pki.*"%>
```

and it would mark them red.

`DB` also depends on some packages that are in `Scheduler`, but since they are not modules, I cannot add them as `dependencies` in `Project settings`.

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

I would like to ideally be able to debug on my local machine, but I can't find the way to make it work :(

I am not using Maven..

Comment: Which directory do you have identified as "sources"? The import will be based on the source root.

Comment: I was doing many scenarios: I had  JavaSource in Scheduler set to source, and also the one in Accounting and one in DB, but something else was complaining when I did this so I removed all of them. Should I mark the entire folder as source? i.e.Scheduler, or what should I do? and should other folders be marked as Resources? I am unsure how to do this?

Comment: You checked out the whole svn repository. Try to only checkout directories below "trunk". The source directory is "JavaSource"

Comment: @Stefan thanks for the tip. When I checked them one by one, those below trunk, it asked me "Would you like to create IntelliJ  project for the sources you have checked out?" Should I say YES?

Comment: Yes, that will create some config files in the root of the project, to save IntelliJ's settings.

Comment: @Stefan so every time I check out directory under trunk, when it asks me to create a new project I should say yes? meaning each one of the sub-directories of different trunks is a project on its own?

Comment: No, I think they all belong to a single project. Someone just forgot to check in the main folder too. Create a Java web project with IJ and import those three folders into it.